# NodeMCU redirect after submitting form

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I've got a problem with my NodeMCU server. It's serving a simple form. After submitting it, I want it to serve page with information about successful configuration. However I don't know how to do it. I really tried to make it work but I've failed.

Could anyone help me? It's all about automatically showing / redirecting the user to another page. Here is the code:

```
sv = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)

function receiver(sck, payload)
    print(payload)
    payloadSsid = string.match(payload, "ssid=(.+)&pswd")
    payloadPswd = string.match(payload, "pswd=(.+)&destinationAddress")

if (payloadSsid ~= nil) and (payloadPswd ~= nil) and then
sck:close()
sv:close()
wifi.ap.dhcp.stop()    

end 
end

if sv then
  sv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", receiver)
    conn:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nServer: Sensor " .. node.chipid() .."\r\n\n")
    conn:send("</head><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\"><body><h1>Sensor " .. node.chipid() .. " configuration page</h1>")
    conn:send("<FORM action=\"\" method=\"POST\">")
    conn:send("<h3>WIFI credentials</h3><br>")
    conn:send("SSID*:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"ssid\" placeholder=\"SSID\" required></input><br>")
    conn:send("Password*:<br><input type=\"password\"name=\"pswd\" placeholder=\"password\" required></input><br>") 
    conn:send("<button type=\"submit\">Submit</button><br>")
    conn:send("</form></html></body>")
  end)
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: This will fail in any recent version of NodeMCU as `conn:send` is asynchronous: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend. I suggest you consider using https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver rather then building everything yourself.